# HTML/JS referencing IDs

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm wondering how to reference an HTML id or a class in JavaScript in the following context.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var menu = document.querySelector('ul'), 
            menulink = document.querySelector('**REFERENCE CLASS**');

        menulink.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            menu.classList.toggle('active');
            e.preventDeafult();
        });
    })();

</script>
```

I'd appreciate any help I can get, thanks.

Comment: `preventDeafult` That won't work. If you're trying to use `querySelector`, did you try looking up how selector strings work?

Comment: If you have HTML `id` attributes in place, the best API to use is `.getElementByID("idHere")`. Also (FYI), `type="text/javascript"` hasn't been needed for several years as it is the default for a `script` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have an element with `class` attribute equals to "my-class" and you want to select that element with `JavaScript`. Here as an example i'll select an element based on its `class` attribute and change his color to green using only `JavaScript`.

```js
// referencing the element with class attribute containing my-class using querySelector() method that you used it in your code, notice the " . " (dot) before the class-name
var myClassDiv = document.querySelector('.my-class');
// changing the text color to green 
myClassDiv.style.color = '#0F0';
```

```html
<div class="my-class">by default my color is black but JavaScript made me green !</div>
```

**Explanation:**

1. The method `querySelector()` receives a string representing a fully qualified `CSS` selector. i.e `querySelector('body #main > ul.menu > li.class-name')` and as the same selector can match many elements in the same document this method returns only the first element matched by the selector.
2. To get all the elements matching a selector you could use `querySelectorAll()` that returns an `array` of the matched elements.
3. You wanted to select an element based on it's class-name, `JavaScript` provides a method that fetches all the elements based on a class-name: `getElementsByClassName()` that returns an `array` containing the matched ones even if there is only one element. It rereceives a string representing a class-name, **NOT** as you write it in `CSS` i.e getElementsByClassName('class-name') NO dot before the class-name.

To do the same task as we did in the top of that answer 
, I'll be using the `getElementsByClassName()` instead of `querySelector()`.

```js
// referencing the element with class attribute containing my-class 
var myClassDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('my-class')[0];
// changing the text color to green 
myClassDiv.style.color = '#0F0';
```

```html
<div class="my-class">by default my color is black but JavaScript made me green !</div>
```

Hope I pushed you further.

Comment: `.querySelectorAll()` is generally preferred over `.getElementsByClassName()` as the former returns a static node list and the latter returns a live node list. Live node lists are sometimes useful with a dynamic DOM, but there is a heavy performance price you pay for the live update feature they provide. When the DOM doesn't change, they are extremely inefficient way to get a collection of elements with no justification for the performance hit.

Comment: @ScottMarcus yeah you're right, but sticking to the OP's needs I didn't mention performance, I could do it but that will make the answer longer with "side notes" so I tried to be specific to the needs. I really appreciate your comment, helpful and short, good point tough.